# Need help in android image sliding animation

Tags: android, eclipse, animation, android-studio

I am doing an app related to transportation.so i need to animate the image of a bus from left to right (coming from left stops at center and exit from the center to right) i want to repeat this animation until my splash screen ends.this is like what red bus uses when loading another activity.can you  help me with the code?

I tried this but its giving wrong output

```
<animation-list
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="true">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/sp1" android:duration="1000"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/sp2" android:duration="1000" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/sp3" android:duration="1000" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/sp4" android:duration="1000" />
```

and this in main

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    ImageView mMailTab = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.splash_view);
    mMailTab.setImageBitmap(null);
    mMailTab.setBackgroundResource( R.anim.splash_anim );

    final AnimationDrawable mailAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) mMailTab.getBackground();
    mMailTab.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if ( mailAnimation != null ) mailAnimation.start();
          }
    });
```

Comment: Please show us your code what you have tried.

Comment: what u have tried yet?

Comment: i tried this in anim folder

<animation-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="true">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/sp1" android:duration="1000"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/sp2" android:duration="1000" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/sp3" android:duration="1000" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/sp4" android:duration="1000" />
   
</animation-list>

Comment: this in main.java

getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
  ImageView mMailTab = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.splash_view);
  mMailTab.setImageBitmap(null);
  mMailTab.setBackgroundResource( R.anim.splash_anim );
  
  final AnimationDrawable mailAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) mMailTab.getBackground();
  mMailTab.post(new Runnable() {
      @Override
   public void run() {
          if ( mailAnimation != null ) mailAnimation.start();
        }
  });

Answer (score 0):

here is The Code use This ......
First Create A Folder in like res/animation
    Then Create an `xml` ie `move.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" >

    <translate
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromXDelta="-75%p"
        android:toXDelta="75%p" >
    </translate>
    <translate
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromXDelta="-75%p"
        android:startOffset="800"
        android:toXDelta="75%p" >
    </translate>

</set>
```

Then to apply use this

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
            getApplicationContext(), R.animation.move);
    animation.setDuration(yourTime);
    imageView.startAnimation(animation);
```